# Azure Active Directory and Multi-tenant apps authorization

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

After registering an application in AAD, there seems to be no way of managing tenant access control in the Azure portal.

From what i have been reading, the burden of allowing or denying a particular tenant falls on the developer in the app code.  All users. from any AAD domain can access a registered app  by default (after Grant Permissions )..

If this is the case than this is a piss-poor model.  This means that "allowed-tenants" table can potentially grow to millions of records, and each time a user logs in, a query would need to check his tennantID against that table..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, currently there is no such feature make allow/deny list for a multi-tenant app. We could control that in app , by checking tid claim in JWT token , you could create a deny list( records will less then allow list) and check whether tid is in the deny list . And [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/12401940-add-ability-to-limit-a-multi-tenant-application-to) is a feedback which requires same feature .

Comment: Deny list doesn't make sense, since all are allowed by default. That list would be infinite

Comment: Actually what we do in an app that must allow signin from one of two tenants, is we check that the tid claim is one of them. And if not, send the user to an error page. It's not hard to implement on the app side.